# Converting XML text to many different classes

Tags: java, android, xml

My issue is converting text within a field to a specific class (for purposes of launching different Activities). My XML file will be expanded into two different classes. However, each object will have a reference to **another class** (which is an Activity), and this reference is unique for each item in the **XML** file. So, it will look similar to the following, albeit with more properties:

```
<Group name="Header 1">
   <DestinationClass>ActivityA.class</DestinationClass>
   <Child name="Child 1">
      <DestinationClass>ActivityA1.class</DestinationClass>
   </Child>
   <Child name="Child 2">
      <DestinationClass>ActivityA2.class</DestinationClass>
   </Child>
</Group>

<Group name="Header 2">
   <DestinationClass>ActivityB.class</DestinationClass>
   <Child name="Child 1">
      <DestinationClass>ActivityB1.class</DestinationClass>
   </Child>
</Group>
```

In the end, I'm trying to mimic **AndroidManifest.xml** file in a way. This XML file will be parsed then eventually turned into an **ExpandableListView** on my Navigation Drawer. Ultimately, I'm trying to avoid coding in every detail of the menu, and would rather also have it all in one place. The classes look similar to the following:

```
public class NavListGroup {
    // Id for this group, for later matching
    private int mGroupId;

    // The displayed name of this Group
    private String mGroupName;

        // As needed for now, only launches an activity
    // Determines the destination
    private Class mActivityDestination;

    // Easily determines if the group has children under it
    private boolean mHasChildren = false;

    // Holds all the children items that belongs under this group
    private List<NavListChild> mChildrenList;

}


public class NavListChild {
    // Id for this child item, for later matching
    private int mChildId;

    // The displayed name of this child item
    private String mChildName;

        // As needed for now, only launches an activity
    // Determines the destination
    private Class mActivityDestination;
}
```

(The XML also holds the ID as well, if I still need it in the end)

The reason for needing the member Class variable is that, once the group or child item is clicked, an intent will be launched- however, every item has a different activity/class. I could use a master list [matched via Ids to classes in a second list that's coded directly in], but that would go against the purpose of making the XML file in the first place.

I've tried searching everywhere for an answer- it's not really serializing objects (although I'm guessing it's considered **deserializing** XML into two objects, in this case), but it's more of a problem of converting a text to a class similar to in the AndroidManifest xml file, where an Activity is defined. I also couldn't find the code that parses the AndroidManifest file either, so no leads there.

Comment: Where is this XML file stored? Are you going download it over the internet or is it placed inside res/xml folder?

Comment: It's placed inside the res/xml file, rather than over the internet

Comment: Then I don't see a point to setup your navigation like this. The only time when you can change this file is during development. You will not benefit from it as far as I can see. It's an overkill. Why can't you follow standard approach for creating NavigationDrawer?

Comment: If you mean standard approach as in creating a list and applying the properties one by one, then adding it to the list view at once- it reduces the flexibility of the code as well as the ability to read and edit it easily. On another note, this is used on a navigation drawer that's part of a central fragment, that's then added to every activity that uses the drawer. Once the activity sets up the drawer, it needs to pass in a value either way that represents its position in the list- therefore, the list needs to be easily readable and accessible while preferably not compromising flexibility

Comment: Hmm.. I guess a better way to put it, is that I'm planning on expanding this further. There may be multiple different menus, or the menu may be unknown during development time (say by downloading over the internet for some reason). At the moment, I could code in each group and child (with each id, destination class, name, order, and respective children), but I'd have to face this hurdle eventually it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative you could take [iosched](https://github.com/google/iosched) of Google as example. They have created a `BaseActivity` that handles common features such as `NavigationDrawer`.

Regarding XML over coding issue. You can take an advantage of the XML resources such as string arrays for example. Your `ExpandableListView` will use an `Adapter` which may load it's data from that string array or multiple arrays defining list item names and destinations. What I mean is that instead loading entire customized XML file, make use of the built in [resource ecosystem](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) that is easily accessible from the code.

Besides, I would understand if this XML would be expanded later by person that does not know anything about coding Android. But you are defining there classes as destinations, right? And if it's just you who is going to edit that file then it shouldn't be that much difficult for you to modify code which can also be gracefully maintained.

That's my opinion.

Comment: Hmm... How would I use the resource ecosystem to reference different Activities? I still can't figure out how to NOT directly code in that part.